# Mongoose returns uniterable array from Schema.find({})?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to retrieve some data from my mongo DB, and it returns all what I need, but its in some weird structure that I can't seem to get into, can't for loop through it, can't iterate with i, can't iterate through Object.entries, either!

The data:

```
[
  {
    _id: 666,
    username: 'VioPaige',
    email: '<email>',
    verifcode: 'noverifcode',
    confirmed: false
  },
  {
    _id: 73,
    username: 'DogeKnight',
    email: '<email>',
    verifcode: 'noverifcode',
    confirmed: true
  },
  {
    _id: 1000,
    username: 'BlockAccount',
    email: '<email>',
    verifcode: 'noverifcode',
    confirmed: true
  }
]
```

Is there any way I can still iterate through it?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: you get a cursor, and the documents in batches, if your result is small(fit in memory) you can do `.toArray` else you should use the cursor methods [see this also](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/querycursor.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already had same problem.

Try to use **lean** option. [Mongoose With Lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

```
const docs = await YourModel.findOne().lean();
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed converted it to a regular array that I could iterate over!

Answer (score 0):

Try chaining toArray method after find

```
Find({}).toArray(function(err, data) {
 console.log(data);
}
```